# Favicon is not displayed in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm using Next.js (^13.4.7) with the App directory.  I want to display favicon but it is not displayed. The favicon is in the public folder. The format is jpg.

If I go to http://localhost:3000/favicon.png the image is displayed.

```
// import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import { Providers } from "@/app/providers";
import { Header } from "@/components/Header";
import Head from "next/head";

// const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata = {
  title: "***",
  description: "***",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <Head>
        <link href={"/favicon.png"} rel={"icon"} sizes="any" />
        <meta charSet="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      </Head>
      <body>
        <Providers>
          <Header />
          {children}
        </Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Comment: If you have a JPG file, why would you expect the PNG extension to work? Link to the actual file that your image has. Also, don't use templating if all you're putting in is string literals: don't use `href={"/favicon.jpg"} rel={"icon"}`, use the normal `href="/favicon.jpg" rel="icon"`.

Answer (score 0):

For next.js app directory, you need to keep the favicon file in the app directory and not the public directory.

Along with icon, you can also add social media / opengraph images also in the app directory.

Answer (score 0):

With the [`app`](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure) router (directory), do not add that `Head` or the `link` yourself. Instead, add the file in the right directory with the right name and extension as shown on the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/metadata/app-icons):

[image]

If you are still not seeing it, try hard refreshing the browser, stopping your development server, and starting again.